# c# NLog local-ip cached

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I read that with NLog 4.6.8 there is a layout to acquire the local IP address and, for better performance, use a cached ip value.

I'm using a layout like this:

```
 <target xsi:type="Network"
       ...
       ...
       layout="SrcIP:${local-ip:cached:true}, ${message}"/>
```

but I'm not sure this is the correct syntax, as the documentation is not very clear to me.
Can anyone tell me if this syntax is correct or not?
If not, how should I cache ip indefinitely?
Thanks so much

Comment: `${local-ip:cachedSeconds=60}` or `${local-ip:cached=true}`. See also the wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Local-IP-Address-Layout-Renderer

Comment: So the syntax I used is correct right? 
    ${local-ip:cached:true}

Comment: Before you used `${local-ip:chacedcached:true}` now you use `${local-ip:cached:true}`, but the correct value is `${local-ip:cached=true}`

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Rolf Kristensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193178/rolf-kristensen)

The correct syntax is:

```
${local-ip:cached=true}
```

Now it works well and the Warn message local-ip has no default property in the internal NLog log is disappeared.
Thank you